# User Control button click not working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have created a user control that should act like a button in a windows forms application.

It looks like this

```
public partial class ControlButton : UserControl
{
    public ControlButton(String id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Click += new EventHandler(ControlButton_Click);
        this.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(ControlButton_MouseEnter);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the `Click` event does not get fired consistently. It gets clicked like every 5-6 times I click on it. There is no issue with the `MouseEnter` event and it gets fired consistently.

I also tried `this.MouseClick`, `this.MouseDown` events to raise an event, but even these are working inconsistently.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Another control or form is likely handling the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message.

Does this usercontrol have any children and is it focused before you click? This could give us more information to answer your question completely.

Have you looked at the WM_MESSAGEs the control is receiving when you click on it?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer. I do not have in depth knowledge about the internals of the controls. I will try and figure out how to get these messages.

Comment: BTW. It had a child -> a Label().
I removed the label and seems like the control is responding correctly to the clicks! Thanks!!